# Multiplication and Sum in GridView ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a datatable which is bound to GridView datasource as follows.

Overall i want to Multiply 'Quantity' column value with 'Part1 qty' column value until 'column5' cell value is repeating and so on
the result of operation should appear underneath the value as highlighted in red for understanding

[My GridView data currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwZZt.jpg)

I want the following output

[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZNwF.jpg)

My GridMarkup

[My GridMarkup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LesNn.jpg)

What I have done so far is

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int gridViewCellCount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        string[] columnNames = new string[gridViewCellCount];
        for (int k = 0; k < gridViewCellCount; k++)
        {
            columnNames[k] = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell)(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[k])).ContainingField.HeaderText;
        }

        for (int i = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
            GridViewRow previousRow = GridView1.Rows[i - 1];
            
            var result = Array.FindIndex(columnNames, element => element.EndsWith("QTY"));
            var Arraymax=columnNames.Max();
            int maxIndex = columnNames.ToList().IndexOf(Arraymax);
            decimal MultiplicationResult=0;
            int counter = 0;

            for (int j = 8; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                if (row.Cells[j].Text == previousRow.Cells[j].Text)
                {
                    counter++;
                    if (row.Cells[j].Text != "&nbsp;" && result < maxIndex)
                    {
                        var Quantity = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                        var GLQuantity = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[result].Text;
                        var PreviousQuantity= GridView1.Rows[i-1].Cells[1].Text;
                        var PreviousGLQuantity= GridView1.Rows[i-1].Cells[result].Text;
                        //var Quantity = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1];
                        //var GLQuantity = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[Convert.ToInt64(result)].ToString();
                        var GLQ = GLQuantity.TrimEnd(new Char[] { '0' });
                        var PGLQ = PreviousGLQuantity.TrimEnd(new char[] { '0' });
                        if (GLQ == "")
                        {
                            GLQ = 0.ToString();
                        }
                        if (PGLQ == "")
                        {
                            PGLQ = 0.ToString();
                        }

                        MultiplicationResult = Convert.ToDecimal(Quantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(GLQ) + Convert.ToDecimal(PreviousQuantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(PGLQ);

                        object o = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] + " " + MultiplicationResult.ToString();
                        
                        GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text = o.ToString();
                        GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
                        result++;

                    }
                    else
                        result++;

                    if (previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan += 2;
                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = row.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;

                        }
                        row.Cells[j].Visible = false;

                    }

                   
                }

                else
                    result++;
            }
        }
       
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using auto generated columns or templates? Show your grid markup as well.

Comment: Updated my Grid Markup.
I have a stored Procedure which gets all the column and with the help of  below code binding the GridView1

Updated Grid Markup as well

GridView1.DataSource = datatable1;  

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use below Answer

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int gridViewCellCount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        string[] columnNames = new string[gridViewCellCount];
        for (int k = 0; k < gridViewCellCount; k++)
        {
            columnNames[k] = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell)(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[k])).ContainingField.HeaderText;
        }

        for (int i = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
            GridViewRow previousRow = GridView1.Rows[i - 1];

            var result = Array.FindIndex(columnNames, element => element.EndsWith("QTY"));
            var Arraymax = columnNames.Max();
            int maxIndex = columnNames.ToList().IndexOf(Arraymax);
            decimal MultiplicationResult = 0;
            decimal currentCellResult = 0;
           

            for (int j = 8; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                var defaultvalue = row.Cells[j].Text.ToString();
                var defaultvalueArray = defaultvalue.Split(' ');
                var originalMultiplicationResult = defaultvalueArray.Count() == 2 ? defaultvalueArray.Last() : "0";
                var originalCellValue = defaultvalueArray.Count() == 2 ? defaultvalueArray.First() : row.Cells[j].Text.ToString();
                if (originalCellValue == previousRow.Cells[j].Text)
                {
                    
                    if (row.Cells[j].Text != "&nbsp;" && result < maxIndex)
                    {
                        var Quantity = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                        var GLQuantity = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[result].Text;
                        var PreviousQuantity = GridView1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[1].Text;
                        var PreviousGLQuantity = GridView1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[result].Text;
                        var GLQ = GLQuantity.TrimEnd(new Char[] { '0' });
                        var PGLQ = PreviousGLQuantity.TrimEnd(new char[] { '0' });
                        if (GLQ == "")
                        {
                            GLQ = 0.ToString();
                        }
                        if (PGLQ == "")
                        {
                            PGLQ = 0.ToString();
                        }
                        currentCellResult = Convert.ToDecimal(Quantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(GLQ);
                        MultiplicationResult = currentCellResult + Convert.ToDecimal(PreviousQuantity) * Convert.ToDecimal(PGLQ);
                        if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                        {
                            //DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
                            object o = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] + " " + MultiplicationResult.ToString();
                            
                            previousRow.Cells[j].Text = o.ToString();
                            //previousRow.Cells[j].Text = previousRow.Cells[j].Text.Split("");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
                            var t = Convert.ToDecimal(originalMultiplicationResult) - Convert.ToDecimal(currentCellResult) + MultiplicationResult;
                            object o = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] + " " + t.ToString();
                            previousRow.Cells[j].Text = o.ToString();
                            //previousRow.Cells[j].Text.Replace("\n", "<br>");
                        }
                        result++;

                    }
                    else
                        result++;

                    if (previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                    {
                        if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan += 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = row.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;
                        }
                        row.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                    }
                }

                else
                    result++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).